# Is it necessary for an embeddable widget to be in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The main question I have is, is it totally necessary for the embeddable widget to be in an iframe? Will the fact that it's in an iFrame be rejected by some sites for any reason? What kind of tips can you give me?

Btw, the content is just javascript and html, no video, but maybe some images and a javascript that counts down to a certain time.

I have seen this tutorial for doing it in rails. I'm also using rails, although I don't think it matters much. http://www.doorkeeperhq.com/developer/embeddable-javascript-widget

Comment: Asking for links to tutorials is explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I modified the question to avoid the off-topic issue. Maybe that will save it.

Comment: @botbot Actually it's the rules that make Stack Overflow better than most other Q&A sites. They drive down the noise, and promote quality content. If you want to clutter a site up with bad questions, then by all means, please take it elsewhere.

Comment: @meagar totally disagree. i've used this site for years. removed questions about links. kinda funny that a "bad question" is one that asks for legit info. there are tons of ways to filter out content without putting heinous restrictions on users. you're a programmer you should know that.

Comment: @botbot You can debate all you like, but I'm no longer listening. Ask a question on Meta if you really want to raise this as an issue. As it stands, questions asking for a list of off-site links are off topic, and we have a dedicated close-vote reason *explicitly* for those questions: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it**. I don't make the rules, though I happen to agree with this one.

Comment: @meagar i've already said i removed that. anyways, other people are giving good, constructive answers rather than complaining.

Answer (score 1):

If you are displaying untrusted data then you will most certainly want it in an iframe on a separate domain for security reasons. Especially if you have any kind of sensitive information available in the client, such as a session cookie.

In addition you will want it in an iframe because if there are any bugs in the widget it will break the entire page. It may be so bad that a user cannot remove the widget or fix it. A dev may have to go into the database and delete it there.

'just JavaScript' is quite enough, it's never 'just JavaScript'. JavaScript will steal your lunch and punch you in the stomach for it. XSS are pretty much one of the most terrible security vulnerabilities you can have. They defeat everything like logins with passwords and even two factor authentication is useless when you have an XSS issue.

So not only use an iframe, host it on a separate domain.

Problems you run into with using an iframe can depend on the browser and the security restrictions a site may place on an iframe. There are new HTML5 related attributes you can add to iframes to limit their capabilities.

By the way if you are expecting other third parties to implement your widgets on their site without an iframe, that's asking way too much.

Comment: thanks for the answer man and thanks for updating the question. the stackoverflow polic are relentless.